# TFS2013 Build Definition Error while executing postbuild Powershell script

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm getting an error like this, while using the script from build definition(custom SSIS template):

Used the script given in this location:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/24/basic-tfbuild-scripts.aspx

This is the Error message:

**"The argument '$/path/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter."

Exception Message: TF270015: 'GatherItemsForDrop.ps1' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '-196608'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)  Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)    at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)    at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)**

Any thoughts on this? Thanks in Advance.

** Updated - Adding Build Log with PS part**

Perform Final Actions On Agent 00:00

Copy binaries to drop 00:00

Reset the Environment 00:03

Sequence 00:03

Run optional script after MSBuild
 The argument '$/path/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
 Exception Message: TF270015: 'GatherItemsForDrop.ps1' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '-196608'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Note: Both the PS script as well as SSIS Solution is in the same folder in TFS.

Only This much info available. :( ..
Thanks

Comment: Can you post also the build log part with GatherItemsForDrop.ps1?

Comment: Do you really have a team project called "path"?

Comment: yes..the path is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The build system cant find the file. Check that it is checked in to that location and that it is in scope for the build.

Comment: both PS script path as well as ssis solution in the same path. PS Path: '$/path/GatherItemsForDrop.ps1'    and  SSIS Solution Path: '$/path/SSISProject/SSISProject.sln'

Comment: yes..in the workspace..selected the folder where the solution file and powershell script resides..